# Custom queries?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

Is there anyway to create some kind of a custom query or filer on SO?

What I'd like to see is a list of questions asked in the past 7 days with no replies at all, within my set of interested tags, that are asked by users with an acceptance rate > 75%.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=), but none that get the specific results you want.

The closest (i.e., most useful) you can get is the new [My Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) feature (unanswered + interesting tags, sorted descending by votes). Or you can manually input your interesting tags and use the `answers:0` search option to find questions with *literally* zero answers.

There's a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options) pending to add the ability to date filter search results, and there's also a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/is-there-a-way-to-sort-unanswered-my-tag-questions-by-date-newest-first) pending to add the ability to sort the My Tags feature by most recent first.

The one part of what you're asking for that will never happen is filtering by a users accept rate. [Read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47600/i-was-going-to-answer-your-question-til-i-saw-your-accept-rate) for context. (And before you ask, [searching by users' reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation) falls into the same category.)

Answer (score 2):

Now there's [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), where you can write your own queries in SQL. You can take a look at a few and fork from those to your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the search box. Add these to your "query"

- No replies - answers:0
- Tags - [java] [anothertag] [yetanothertag]

For past 7 days, just sort by date. Currently there is no way to search by acceptance rate.

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search